# Block all threads on a given object

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to basically write a lock for the current project I'm working on that when a connection has failed, all threads calling a given method should hang until the connection is reestablished.

How do I do this again in Java? It's been a while since I've had to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wait on a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) inside the method.  The condition would be something like:

```
while (!conn.isConnected) condition.await()
```

There's a lot more to it than this pseudo-code, of course.

You might want to read up on the so-called [circuit breaker pattern](http://timross.wordpress.com/2008/02/10/implementing-the-circuit-breaker-pattern-in-c/) too.  Kind of a buzz-wordy thing, but it's goal is to manage integration points that can fail, like your connection to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just not return from the method until the connection is reestablished? An actual implementation will depend on this method and how this connection is managed. You could either `wait()` on an Object, and when another thread that's responsible for reconnecting re-establishes the connection, call `notify()` to unblock the method. This way, anything that's calling the method will block because the method never returns when the connection is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) wait() and notifyAll() methods:

```
public final void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException
```

> Causes current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or a
>   specified amount of time has elapsed.

```
 public final void notifyAll()
```

> Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor. A
>   thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait
>   methods.

However, this is by no means the only solution open to you. There are other [synchronisation mechanisms in Java](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java%20synchronization%20mechanisms)